# Spawn a prefab at random y position with different gap between prefabs

Tags: unity, c#, random, spawning

I have this code, and I want to be able to spawn my Wall prefab at random heights and gaps between the upper wall and wall under it, but it seems that my code will only spawn the wall with same gap between the walls.

```
public GameObject[] wall;
public float spawnMin = 1f;
public float spawnMax = 2f;
public Vector3 posWall = new Vector3(0,-4,0);
public float sizeWall = 1.0f;
private Vector3 dir = Vector3.up;

void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}

IEnumerator Spawn() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        GameObject wallTemp = (GameObject)Instantiate(
                wall [Random.Range (0, wall.Length)], posWall, Quaternion.identity);
        //Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], pos, Quaternion.identity);
        posWall += dir * sizeWall;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
    }
}
```

I am looking for something like in the following diagram:

[image: I want the walls to be placed at the side of the screen, with random y co-ordinates.]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your update, you describe placing the walls on either side of a room. From your description and diagram, you intend to use random heights for the walls. Instead, I would recommend randomly deciding *if* the wall is going to be placed.

Consider your diagram. In the diagram, you have walls of varying height; but if you consider each *segment* to be a wall, it is the amount of consecutive segments that change, not the actual height of the walls.

---

### The Solution

The script, below, will generate walls randomly as shown in your diagram. Rather than randomly changing the *height* of each wall, I sequentially move to each segment, and use a random number to determine *if* I am going to place a wall. Note that I have included an additional `Editor` class, to allow us to randomly generate the wall from the inspector. This allows us to quickly view multiple iterations.

#### WallGenerator

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class WallGenerator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    /// <summary>The X-Coordinate for the left wall.</summary>
    public float leftWallPosition;
    /// <summary>The X-Coordinate for the right wall.</summary>
    public float rightWallPosition;
    /// <summary>The Y-Coordinate for the wall at the base of the level.</summary>
    public float wallBasePosition;

    /// <summary>The height of each individual floor. Ideally, this value should 
    /// match the wall height, to avoid clipping.</summary>
    public float floorHeight;
    /// <summary>The amount of floors in the level.</summary>
    public int floorCount;

    /// <summary>How frequently are walls spawned? At 1, walls should spawn 
    /// every time. At 2, walls should spawn roughly half the time. Any negative 
    /// number is converted to 1 before use.</summary>
    public int wallFrequency;

    /// <summary>Array of prefab wall pieces to randomly select from.</summary>
    public GameObject[] prefabWall;
    /// <summary>Holds reference to pieces that have already been placed.</summary>
    public List<GameObject> oldWall;      

    /// <summary>Generates the wall.</summary>
    public void GenerateWall()
    {
        // Destroy the old wall, if there is one.
        // This is only to allow quick repetition.
        DestroyOldWall();

        // For each floor, 
        for (int i = 0; i < floorCount; i++)
        {
            // Spawn a wall at the left position, and spawn a wall at the right position.
            SpawnWall(leftWallPosition, (i * floorHeight));
            SpawnWall(rightWallPosition, (i * floorHeight));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Spawns a wall piece. May randomly choose not to.</summary>
    /// <param name="xPosition">X position of the wall piece.</param>
    /// <param name="yPosition">Y position of the wall piece.</param>
    void SpawnWall(float xPosition, float yPosition)
    {
        // If wallFrequency is less than one, 
        if (wallFrequency < 1)
        {
            // We have a logical issue performing the Random function;
            // Reset wallFrequency to one, walls should always spawn.
            wallFrequency = 1;
        }

        // Find a random number between zero and wallFrequency, 
        // and if that number is zero, 
        if(Random.Range(0, wallFrequency) == 0)
        {
            // Load a random wall piece from the prefabWall, and determine the position.
            GameObject wallPiece = prefabWall[Random.Range(0, prefabWall.Length)];
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(xPosition, yPosition, 0);

            // Instantiate the wall piece, and load it in to the oldWall list.
            wallPiece = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPiece, position, Quaternion.identity);
            oldWall.Add(wallPiece);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Checks if a wall already exists, 
    /// and destroys it immediately, if it does.</summary>
    void DestroyOldWall()
    {
        // If the old wall list is not empty, 
        if (oldWall.Count > 0)
        {
            // for each wall object in the old wall list, 
            for (int i = 0; i < oldWall.Count; i++)
            {
                // destroy the wall piece immediately, 
                // so it will take effect in the editor.
                DestroyImmediate(oldWall[i]);
            }

            // Clear out the old wall list.
            oldWall.Clear();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>Custom editor to allow us to trigger the GenerateWall.</summary>
[CustomEditor(typeof(WallGenerator))]
public class WallGeneratorEditor : Editor
{

    /// <summary>Calls on drawing the GUI for the inspector.</summary>
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Draw the default inspector.
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        // Grab a reference to the target script, so we can identify it as a 
        // WallGenerator, instead of a simple Object.
        WallGenerator wallGenerator = (WallGenerator)target;

        // Create a Button for "Generate Wall"
        if(GUILayout.Button("Generate Wall"))
        {
            // if it is clicked, call the GenerateWall method from WallGenerator.
            wallGenerator.GenerateWall();
        }
    }
}
```

#### WallGenerator in Action

Below, you can see `WallGenerator` generating walls, where `wallFrequency == 0`, `wallFrequency == 1`, `wallFrequency == 2`, and `wallFrequency == 10`. As you can see, the lower frequency reliably builds an entire wall, where a frequency of 2+ randomly skips.

[image: The walls completely regenerate with each iteration of GenerateWall, and respond appropriately to frequencies of 0, 1, 2 and 10.]

---

### Considerations

#### The Dimensions of the Building

Given that the walls are all being placed using a script, it is essential that you provide the correct values relative to your building. It would be a good idea to generate your wall a couple of times, in the editor, to visually confirm that the walls are being placed correctly.

Note that if you increase the value of `floorCount`, the walls will potentially build higher. You might manipulate this variable to place walls on the roof, for example.

[image: The important variables laid out on the provided diagram.]

#### The Wall Piece

It is important to have reliable wall pieces, when using the above script. For example, it is assumed that the point of origin will be the base of the wall. If you simply scaled out a cube, the point of origin would be in the center, and cause your walls to spawn in the ceiling.

The best way to solve this problem, and to keep everything neat, is to simply create a separate point of origin. Place a cube at the center base of your wall, and parent your actual wall piece to it. Now, your wall will spawn at the base. You can remove everything from the base cube, apart from the transform.

[image: A wall piece shown with its base piece visible.]